# MLE of truncated Pareto distribution

Tags: pareto-distribution

I am trying to apply truncated Pareto distribution to a dataset, but I am not able to find a close form MLE for the shape parameter alpha. Could anyone help me with this: how to estimate the shape parameter for the truncated Pareto distribution.

Comment: Perhaps see [Aban et al. (2006)](https://www.stt.msu.edu/users/mcubed/TPareto.pdf)

Comment: Just to remove any chance of ambiguity, I presume you mean right-truncated?

Comment: yes, right-truncated.

Comment: @BruceET the mentioned paper helps a lot. I saw that earlier, but it took some time for me to understand that a nice-looking solution for shape parameter alpha does not exist for truncated Pareto. I used Matlab to get a numerical solution. Thanks!